# Convert SpatialLinesDataFrame with multiple lines to one SpatialPolygonsDataFrame in R

Tags: r

I have a list of 8 SpatialLinesDataFrames which I extracted from a `move` object with `raster2contour`in `move` package.

I have been applying the following function to transform them to SpatialPolygonsDataFrame:

```
line.to.polygone <- function(x, y, z, q){y <- st_as_sf(x)   
z <- st_polygonize(y)  
q <- as(z, "Spatial"); q}
```

This works fine for SLDF that contain one line, but for those that have multiple lines I get an error:
`Error in SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(x, y, match.ID = match.ID, ...) :  Object length mismatch: x has 2 Polygons objects, but y has 1 rows`

Is there a way to join the lines into a single one or a better way to tranform them into SpatialPolygonsDataFrame?

This is the first object of the list:

```
$data
    level
C_1  0.99

$lines
$lines[[1]]
An object of class "Lines"
Slot "Lines":
[[1]]
An object of class "Line"
Slot "coords":
          [,1]    [,2]
  [1,] 4560109 2582784
  [2,] 4560071 2582882
  [3,] 4560055 2582987
  [4,] 4560032 2583091
  [5,] 4560025 2583196
  [6,] 4560019 2583301
  [7,] 4560011 2583405
  [8,] 4560009 2583510
  [9,] 4560009 2583615
 [10,] 4560013 2583719
 [11,] 4560018 2583824
 [12,] 4560030 2583929
 [13,] 4560040 2584033
 [14,] 4560052 2584138
 [15,] 4560085 2584243
 [16,] 4560107 2584347
 [17,] 4560109 2584356
 [18,] 4560144 2584452
 [19,] 4560213 2584529
 [20,] 4560239 2584557
 [21,] 4560295 2584661
 [22,] 4560318 2584682
 [23,] 4560364 2584766
 [24,] 4560403 2584871
 [25,] 4560423 2584919
 [26,] 4560465 2584975
 [27,] 4560527 2585016
 [28,] 4560632 2585075
 [29,] 4560636 2585080
 [30,] 4560683 2585185
 [31,] 4560736 2585279
 [32,] 4560749 2585289
 [33,] 4560841 2585333
 [34,] 4560924 2585394
 [35,] 4560946 2585425
 [36,] 4561050 2585495
 [37,] 4561057 2585499
 [38,] 4561155 2585533
 [39,] 4561260 2585590
 [40,] 4561323 2585603
 [41,] 4561364 2585625
 [42,] 4561469 2585673
 [43,] 4561513 2585708
 [44,] 4561573 2585759
 [45,] 4561678 2585798
 [46,] 4561703 2585813
 [47,] 4561783 2585842
 [48,] 4561887 2585860
 [49,] 4561992 2585874
 [50,] 4562096 2585898
 [51,] 4562201 2585910
 [52,] 4562290 2585917
 [53,] 4562306 2585921
 [54,] 4562410 2585969
 [55,] 4562515 2585993
 [56,] 4562579 2586022
 [57,] 4562620 2586043
 [58,] 4562724 2586070
 [59,] 4562829 2586101
 [60,] 4562875 2586127
 [61,] 4562933 2586147
 [62,] 4563038 2586165
 [63,] 4563143 2586205
 [64,] 4563247 2586225
 [65,] 4563282 2586231
 [66,] 4563352 2586264
 [67,] 4563426 2586336
 [68,] 4563456 2586353
 [69,] 4563561 2586382
 [70,] 4563666 2586412
 [71,] 4563717 2586441
 [72,] 4563770 2586510
 [73,] 4563831 2586546
 [74,] 4563875 2586574
 [75,] 4563930 2586650
 [76,] 4563980 2586685
 [77,] 4564084 2586727
 [78,] 4564159 2586755
 [79,] 4564189 2586778
 [80,] 4564232 2586860
 [81,] 4564290 2586964
 [82,] 4564293 2586967
 [83,] 4564398 2587021
 [84,] 4564485 2587069
 [85,] 4564503 2587089
 [86,] 4564531 2587174
 [87,] 4564607 2587262
 [88,] 4564632 2587278
 [89,] 4564712 2587373
 [90,] 4564715 2587383
 [91,] 4564752 2587488
 [92,] 4564816 2587557
 [93,] 4564881 2587592
 [94,] 4564921 2587635
 [95,] 4564978 2587697
 [96,] 4565026 2587723
 [97,] 4565109 2587802
 [98,] 4565130 2587836
 [99,] 4565215 2587906
[100,] 4565235 2587923
[101,] 4565340 2588004
[102,] 4565344 2588011
[103,] 4565444 2588084
[104,] 4565549 2588111
[105,] 4565558 2588116
[106,] 4565653 2588214
[107,] 4565670 2588220
[108,] 4565758 2588262
[109,] 4565863 2588305
[110,] 4565895 2588325
[111,] 4565967 2588354
[112,] 4566072 2588372
[113,] 4566177 2588386
[114,] 4566281 2588403
[115,] 4566386 2588409
[116,] 4566490 2588420
[117,] 4566595 2588423
[118,] 4566700 2588425
[119,] 4566798 2588430
[120,] 4566804 2588431
[121,] 4566909 2588439
[122,] 4567013 2588447
[123,] 4567118 2588482
[124,] 4567223 2588505
[125,] 4567284 2588534
[126,] 4567327 2588546
[127,] 4567432 2588565
[128,] 4567537 2588583
[129,] 4567641 2588624
[130,] 4567722 2588639
[131,] 4567746 2588648
[132,] 4567850 2588691
[133,] 4567916 2588744
[134,] 4567955 2588774
[135,] 4568060 2588820
[136,] 4568092 2588848
[137,] 4568164 2588878
[138,] 4568269 2588901
[139,] 4568373 2588924
[140,] 4568446 2588953
[141,] 4568478 2588978
[142,] 4568583 2589023
[143,] 4568625 2589058
[144,] 4568687 2589104
[145,] 4568792 2589146
[146,] 4568840 2589162
[147,] 4568897 2589173
[148,] 4569001 2589212
[149,] 4569106 2589229
[150,] 4569210 2589245
[151,] 4569300 2589267
[152,] 4569315 2589275
[153,] 4569420 2589302
[154,] 4569524 2589352
[155,] 4569629 2589371
[156,] 4569635 2589372
[157,] 4569733 2589381
[158,] 4569838 2589398
[159,] 4569943 2589405
[160,] 4570047 2589410
[161,] 4570152 2589417
[162,] 4570257 2589419
[163,] 4570361 2589418
[164,] 4570466 2589416
[165,] 4570570 2589412
[166,] 4570675 2589400
[167,] 4570780 2589392
[168,] 4570884 2589383
[169,] 4570932 2589372
[170,] 4570989 2589350
[171,] 4571094 2589323
[172,] 4571189 2589267
[173,] 4571198 2589265
[174,] 4571303 2589250
[175,] 4571407 2589233
[176,] 4571512 2589188
[177,] 4571606 2589162
[178,] 4571617 2589158
[179,] 4571721 2589106
[180,] 4571764 2589058
[181,] 4571826 2588985
[182,] 4571876 2588953
[183,] 4571930 2588938
[184,] 4572035 2588862
[185,] 4572065 2588848
[186,] 4572140 2588787
[187,] 4572190 2588744
[188,] 4572244 2588697
[189,] 4572277 2588639
[190,] 4572349 2588566
[191,] 4572402 2588534
[192,] 4572454 2588474
[193,] 4572491 2588430
[194,] 4572558 2588388
[195,] 4572607 2588325
[196,] 4572640 2588220
[197,] 4572663 2588137
[198,] 4572677 2588116
[199,] 4572767 2588034
[200,] 4572781 2588011
[201,] 4572808 2587906
[202,] 4572832 2587802
[203,] 4572868 2587697
[204,] 4572872 2587664
[205,] 4572896 2587592
[206,] 4572954 2587488
[207,] 4572976 2587383
[208,] 4572977 2587382
[209,] 4572998 2587278
[210,] 4573029 2587174
[211,] 4573039 2587069
[212,] 4573054 2586964
[213,] 4573056 2586860
[214,] 4573055 2586755
[215,] 4573046 2586650
[216,] 4573035 2586546
[217,] 4573024 2586441
[218,] 4572989 2586336
[219,] 4572977 2586273
[220,] 4572970 2586231
[221,] 4572919 2586127
[222,] 4572889 2586022
[223,] 4572872 2585970
[224,] 4572865 2585917
[225,] 4572830 2585813
[226,] 4572806 2585708
[227,] 4572782 2585603
[228,] 4572767 2585577
[229,] 4572689 2585499
[230,] 4572663 2585453
[231,] 4572648 2585394
[232,] 4572583 2585289
[233,] 4572558 2585218
[234,] 4572536 2585185
[235,] 4572458 2585080
[236,] 4572454 2585077
[237,] 4572349 2585009
[238,] 4572322 2584975
[239,] 4572274 2584871
[240,] 4572244 2584807
[241,] 4572204 2584766
[242,] 4572140 2584732
[243,] 4572035 2584681
[244,] 4572012 2584661
[245,] 4571953 2584557
[246,] 4571930 2584537
[247,] 4571826 2584493
[248,] 4571769 2584452
[249,] 4571721 2584380
[250,] 4571674 2584347
[251,] 4571617 2584307
[252,] 4571520 2584243
[253,] 4571512 2584240
[254,] 4571407 2584170
[255,] 4571303 2584141
[256,] 4571291 2584138
[257,] 4571198 2584084
[258,] 4571153 2584033
[259,] 4571094 2583962
[260,] 4571027 2583929
[261,] 4570989 2583918
[262,] 4570884 2583859
[263,] 4570780 2583831
[264,] 4570747 2583824
[265,] 4570675 2583785
[266,] 4570613 2583719
[267,] 4570570 2583695
[268,] 4570466 2583667
[269,] 4570361 2583637
[270,] 4570318 2583615
[271,] 4570257 2583546
[272,] 4570189 2583510
[273,] 4570152 2583490
[274,] 4570078 2583405
[275,] 4570047 2583388
[276,] 4569943 2583357
[277,] 4569838 2583325
[278,] 4569794 2583301
[279,] 4569733 2583233
[280,] 4569664 2583196
[281,] 4569629 2583176
[282,] 4569524 2583117
[283,] 4569501 2583091
[284,] 4569420 2583047
[285,] 4569315 2583017
[286,] 4569256 2582987
[287,] 4569210 2582938
[288,] 4569106 2582884
[289,] 4569102 2582882
[290,] 4569001 2582857
[291,] 4568897 2582804
[292,] 4568792 2582779
[293,] 4568782 2582777
[294,] 4568687 2582731
[295,] 4568621 2582673
[296,] 4568583 2582637
[297,] 4568478 2582588
[298,] 4568455 2582568
[299,] 4568373 2582533
[300,] 4568269 2582510
[301,] 4568164 2582486
[302,] 4568106 2582463
[303,] 4568060 2582426
[304,] 4567955 2582383
[305,] 4567925 2582359
[306,] 4567850 2582329
[307,] 4567746 2582308
[308,] 4567641 2582286
[309,] 4567559 2582254
[310,] 4567537 2582236
[311,] 4567432 2582189
[312,] 4567335 2582149
[313,] 4567327 2582146
[314,] 4567223 2582047
[315,] 4567217 2582044
[316,] 4567118 2582020
[317,] 4567013 2581959
[318,] 4566947 2581940
[319,] 4566909 2581917
[320,] 4566804 2581842
[321,] 4566800 2581835
[322,] 4566734 2581730
[323,] 4566700 2581704
[324,] 4566595 2581658
[325,] 4566521 2581626
[326,] 4566490 2581600
[327,] 4566452 2581521
[328,] 4566386 2581462
[329,] 4566292 2581416
[330,] 4566281 2581407
[331,] 4566232 2581312
[332,] 4566177 2581214
[333,] 4566169 2581207
[334,] 4566072 2581163
[335,] 4565967 2581120
[336,] 4565946 2581102
[337,] 4565875 2580998
[338,] 4565863 2580981
[339,] 4565758 2580905
[340,] 4565739 2580893
[341,] 4565653 2580863
[342,] 4565549 2580802
[343,] 4565493 2580788
[344,] 4565444 2580762
[345,] 4565361 2580684
[346,] 4565340 2580673
[347,] 4565235 2580650
[348,] 4565130 2580628
[349,] 4565026 2580596
[350,] 4564921 2580583
[351,] 4564885 2580579
[352,] 4564816 2580561
[353,] 4564712 2580519
[354,] 4564607 2580501
[355,] 4564503 2580477
[356,] 4564472 2580474
[357,] 4564398 2580468
[358,] 4564293 2580463
[359,] 4564189 2580457
[360,] 4564084 2580461
[361,] 4563980 2580465
[362,] 4563921 2580474
[363,] 4563875 2580481
[364,] 4563770 2580490
[365,] 4563666 2580521
[366,] 4563561 2580541
[367,] 4563456 2580562
[368,] 4563421 2580579
[369,] 4563352 2580594
[370,] 4563247 2580607
[371,] 4563143 2580621
[372,] 4563038 2580656
[373,] 4562933 2580676
[374,] 4562916 2580684
[375,] 4562829 2580748
[376,] 4562729 2580788
[377,] 4562724 2580789
[378,] 4562620 2580809
[379,] 4562515 2580855
[380,] 4562410 2580880
[381,] 4562385 2580893
[382,] 4562306 2580966
[383,] 4562238 2580998
[384,] 4562201 2581014
[385,] 4562096 2581063
[386,] 4562056 2581102
[387,] 4561992 2581129
[388,] 4561887 2581151
[389,] 4561783 2581177
[390,] 4561728 2581207
[391,] 4561678 2581254
[392,] 4561573 2581306
[393,] 4561568 2581312
[394,] 4561469 2581413
[395,] 4561464 2581416
[396,] 4561364 2581440
[397,] 4561260 2581468
[398,] 4561180 2581521
[399,] 4561155 2581554
[400,] 4561050 2581625
[401,] 4561050 2581626
[402,] 4560946 2581660
[403,] 4560860 2581730
[404,] 4560841 2581763
[405,] 4560760 2581835
[406,] 4560736 2581857
[407,] 4560691 2581940
[408,] 4560632 2582003
[409,] 4560563 2582044
[410,] 4560527 2582088
[411,] 4560478 2582149
[412,] 4560423 2582224
[413,] 4560410 2582254
[414,] 4560339 2582359
[415,] 4560318 2582446
[416,] 4560308 2582463
[417,] 4560213 2582554
[418,] 4560200 2582568
[419,] 4560154 2582673
[420,] 4560113 2582777
[421,] 4560109 2582784


[[2]]
An object of class "Line"
Slot "coords":
         [,1]    [,2]
 [1,] 4573500 2589016
 [2,] 4573487 2589058
 [3,] 4573462 2589162
 [4,] 4573436 2589267
 [5,] 4573430 2589372
 [6,] 4573429 2589476
 [7,] 4573434 2589581
 [8,] 4573442 2589686
 [9,] 4573475 2589790
[10,] 4573500 2589888
[11,] 4573502 2589895
[12,] 4573547 2590000
[13,] 4573604 2590049
[14,] 4573637 2590104
[15,] 4573681 2590209
[16,] 4573709 2590238
[17,] 4573814 2590288
[18,] 4573890 2590314
[19,] 4573918 2590335
[20,] 4573983 2590419
[21,] 4574023 2590461
[22,] 4574127 2590505
[23,] 4574159 2590523
[24,] 4574232 2590552
[25,] 4574337 2590562
[26,] 4574441 2590568
[27,] 4574546 2590564
[28,] 4574650 2590554
[29,] 4574755 2590536
[30,] 4574782 2590523
[31,] 4574860 2590463
[32,] 4574933 2590419
[33,] 4574964 2590401
[34,] 4575028 2590314
[35,] 4575069 2590279
[36,] 4575174 2590214
[37,] 4575180 2590209
[38,] 4575255 2590104
[39,] 4575278 2590084
[40,] 4575329 2590000
[41,] 4575347 2589895
[42,] 4575360 2589790
[43,] 4575372 2589686
[44,] 4575373 2589581
[45,] 4575372 2589476
[46,] 4575361 2589372
[47,] 4575350 2589267
[48,] 4575310 2589162
[49,] 4575278 2589060
[50,] 4575277 2589058
[51,] 4575219 2588953
[52,] 4575174 2588918
[53,] 4575069 2588855
[54,] 4575064 2588848
[55,] 4575015 2588744
[56,] 4574964 2588666
[57,] 4574926 2588639
[58,] 4574860 2588611
[59,] 4574755 2588555
[60,] 4574650 2588539
[61,] 4574599 2588534
[62,] 4574546 2588517
[63,] 4574441 2588479
[64,] 4574337 2588475
[65,] 4574232 2588478
[66,] 4574127 2588516
[67,] 4574073 2588534
[68,] 4574023 2588539
[69,] 4573918 2588580
[70,] 4573814 2588619
[71,] 4573769 2588639
[72,] 4573709 2588686
[73,] 4573675 2588744
[74,] 4573628 2588848
[75,] 4573604 2588887
[76,] 4573526 2588953
[77,] 4573500 2589016



Slot "ID":
[1] "C_1"



$bbox
      min     max
x 4560009 4575373
y 2580457 2590568

$proj4string
Coordinate Reference System:
Deprecated Proj.4 representation:
 +proj=laea +lat_0=52 +lon_0=10 +x_0=4321000 +y_0=3210000
+ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs 
WKT2 2019 representation:
PROJCRS["unknown",
    BASEGEOGCRS["unknown",
        DATUM["Unknown based on GRS80 ellipsoid",
            ELLIPSOID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
                ID["EPSG",7019]]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8901]]],
    CONVERSION["unknown",
        METHOD["Lambert Azimuthal Equal Area",
            ID["EPSG",9820]],
        PARAMETER["Latitude of natural origin",52,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8801]],
        PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",10,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8802]],
        PARAMETER["False easting",4321000,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8806]],
        PARAMETER["False northing",3210000,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8807]]],
    CS[Cartesian,2],
        AXIS["(E)",east,
            ORDER[1],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,
                ID["EPSG",9001]]],
        AXIS["(N)",north,
            ORDER[2],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,
                ID["EPSG",9001]]]] 

$class
[1] "SpatialLinesDataFrame"
attr(,"package")
[1] "sp"
```

Comment: Why does that function have four arguments when only `x` is used?

Comment: I think you'll have to give us some sample data if we're to work out what you are doing here.

Comment: @Spacedman I added one of the objects to the post.

As for the function, I am new to R. As I understand it, I get y from f(x), the y from f(y) etc. Is it not needed?

Comment: I guess I see how it could have been one line. When I was writing it I went step by step to see what I would get after each line, so I just didn't correct it afterwards.

This would be the correct way:
line.to.polygone <- function(x){
  as(st_polygonize(st_as_sf(x)), "Spatial")
}?